# After updating nativescript folder and files are not creating in my android phone

Tags: nativescript

I'm able to create a folder if it not exists and save a newly written file in that folder previously. but after updating to latest nativescript the same code was not working and not give error properly.

and also I'm getting an error

> Error: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from >outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. >Is this really what you want?

```
        const fileSystemModule = require("tns-core-modules/file-system");
        const documents = fileSystemModule.knownFolders.documents();
        documents._path = "/storage/emulated/0/";
        const folder = documents.getFolder('Reports/sample/');
        const file = folder.getFile('fileName.xlsx');

        file.writeText(viewModel.get("fileTextContent") || html_content)
            .then((result) => {
                return file.readText()
                    .then((res) => {
                        var toast = Toast.makeText("Exported to Excel Succesfully");
                        toast.show();
                        return res;
                    });
            }).then((result) => {
                console.log("---result---");
                console.log(result); // im getting result, a html string
                var intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(file._path)), "application/vnd.ms-excel");
                application.android.context.startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open Excel..."));
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
```

before updating it was working fine. but now I don't know what happened to this.

Answer (score 0):

It's a new requirement from [Android](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#fant-required) itself. You must add `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag to your intent.

> With Android 9, you cannot start an activity from a non-activity context unless you pass the intent flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. If you attempt to start an activity without passing this flag, the activity does not start, and the system prints a message to the log.

```
intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: i added the above line next to `var intent =` line. to open excel ->"application/vnd.ms-excel" and for pdf -> "application/pdf". in both case I'm getting error : Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity. and while opening pdf application gives stack error. for excel no stackerror only normal error is coming. what to do?

Comment: Without complete error log, I can't comment much. A playground sample would make it easier.

Comment: play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=AVKMPZ&v=3 only for excel i did. as html2pdf library is not supported on playground. File was succesfully created but it cannot be open by intent.

Comment: You are trying to expose file from your app's document directory which can not be accessed by other apps. You will have to implement content provider to allow access or write the file in external storage directory.

Comment: i didn't understood what you said. the above code was working before updating to ns6. but now its not working. can you please make the solution little bit easier. so that i can achieve the behavior without moving out from ns official documentation.

Comment: one more thing is, i can write excel and save it on local but i cannot open that file. so is their any two kind of permission things. one to write and one to open it so....

Comment: As I already mentioned, you can not share files from your app's internal storage. You will have to expose FileProvider for the same, refer this [blog](https://medium.com/@ali.muzaffar/what-is-android-os-fileuriexposedexception-and-what-you-can-do-about-it-70b9eb17c6d0) post for more information and example. FYI, when you upgrade {N}, you are also upgrading underlaying iOS / Android libraries, you must understand the expectations on newer versions. For security and various other reasons, API requirements may change in every version.